# Make next condor job wait until the previous finishes copying input files

Tags: condor

I'm using condor on a computing cluster at the university to manage a large number of jobs. My program reads in two large (~1Gb) input files and produces a small (~100kb) output file. All of my input files are located on the same network disk readable from all condor nodes (we have about 150 of them). I noticed that after I submit a large number of jobs, they start running a lot slower, and I suspect that that is due to IO latency, since the disk head has to move a lot more to read many files concurrently. I would like to optimize this by copying the files to the nodes before running the job. More precisely, I'd like to have only one file copied at a time, so that the disk is read more sequentially. I tried to use

```
should_transfer_files = YES
when_to_transfer_output = ON_EXIT
transfer_input_files = file1, file2
```

but this doesn't seem to force subsequent jobs to wait for the preceding ones to finish copying their files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want job B wait for job A's completion you need to relate them. This can be performed by using DAGs (see DAGman)

```
JOB FIRST a.submit
JOB SECOND b.submit
PARENT FIRST CHILD SECOND
```

In the above example le job defined by b.submit will be executed only if job a.submit finished OK.